# Linux | Shell implementation in C | redirected file includes the prompt

Tags: c, linux, shell, redirect

I'm implementing linux shell in C and seems my output redirection is not working properly. when I run "ls > testFile", I just get an empty prompt while I expect "minishell>", and I found it when opened testFile. why this happen? is this the problem of redirection function itself or functions including redirection? (parse_line or process_cmd)

```
int main(void) {
    char cmdline[MAXLINE];
    while (1) {
        // print prompt
        printf("%s", prompt);
        fflush(stdout);

        // get user input
        if (fgets(cmdline, MAXLINE, stdin) == NULL) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            process_cmd(cmdline);

            fflush(stdout);
        }
}

    return 0;
}

void process_cmd(char *cmdline) {
    int argc;
    char *argv[MAXARGS];
    int status; 

    argc = parse_line(cmdline, argv);

    if (argc == 0) {
        return;
    }

    if (builtin_cmd(argc, argv) == 1) {
        int pid = fork(); 

        if (pid == 0) { 
            argv[argc] = NULL;

            if (execvp(argv[0], argv) == -1) {
                perror ("Error");
            }

            printf("%s: command not found.\n", argv[0]);
            exit(1); 
        }
    wait(&status); 
    }
    return;
}

int parse_line(char *cmdline, char **argv) {
    int count = 0;
    int isRedirected = -1;
    argv[0] = strtok(cmdline, delimiter);


    if (argv[0] == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }

    count++;

    while(1) {
        argv[count] = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
        if (argv[count] == NULL) {
            break;
        }
        count++;
    }

    // redirection check
    for (int index = 0; index < count; index++) {
        if ((strcmp(argv[index], ">") == 0)) {
            if (argv[index+1] == NULL) {
                printf("output file missing.\n");
                printf("USAGE: [command] > [target_file_name]\n");
                return count;
            }
            isRedirected = redirect(argv[index+1]);
            for ( index = index+2; index != count; index++) {
                argv[index-2] = argv[index];
            }
            argv[count-1] = NULL;
            argv[count-2] = NULL;
            count = count - 2;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (isRedirected > 0) {
        reverseRedirected(isRedirected);
    }


    return count;

}

int redirect(char *redirectionDest) {
    int stdOutputFd;
    int fd = open(redirectionDest,O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_WRONLY,S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
    if ((stdOutputFd = dup(1)) == -1) { 
        perror("Error");
        return -1;
    }
    if (dup2(fd, 1) == -1) { 
        perror("Error");
        close(stdOutputFd);
        return -1;
    }

    close(fd);

    return stdOutputFd;
}

void reverseRedirected(int fd) {
    if (dup2(1, fd) == -1) {
        printf("fd dup failed!!\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: Unless you enjoy trouble, *do the redirection between the fork and the exec*. This way you don't have to un-redirect anything, or care about the consequences of failed (un)redirection.

Comment: if it's non-builtin function, that would work perfectly but what if I want to redirect my builtin functions? is there other way to avoid un-redirecting?

Comment: Fork them too (don't exec, just fork).

Comment: sorry for asking again and again... but I think 'builtin function' was a bit ambiguous wording. the function 'builtin-cmd' runs functions that I wrote by my own, not the linux builtin function located in /bin. it doesn't call exec(). should I still need to fork()?

Comment: I understand that. That's why I said "don't exec". There's nothing to exec. Fork, redirect, do the builtin thing, wait. It's easier than redirect, do the builtin thing, redirect back, handle redirecting error. You already have forking and waiting code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never un-redirect after the command finishes, so the shell's output continues to go to the redirected file descriptor.

Edit:

I also just noticed: your `reverseRedirected` function (which is improperly called in the `redirect` function, rather than after the command finishes) has the `dup2` arguments in the wrong order.

Comment: what do you mean by un-redirect?

Comment: You redirect file descriptor 1 when you parse the command line - while you're still "the shell".  After you fork, run the command, and wait for it to execute, file descriptor 1 is still redirected.  You need to either (a) undo the redirection after the command returns, or (b) implement the redirection itself within the child fork, not within the shell.

Comment: Umm... just a teensie-weensie thing, questions like these should really be comments instead of answers, just saying...

Comment: @AdelK sorry, I worded my answer as a question and should not have.  I have reworded it.

Comment: moved reverseRedirection after the command finishes, and changed the order of arguments. and now it works! thanks a lot. it also answers to my other curiosity, too. seems I misunderstood the concept of redirection.

Comment: By the way, I made 'isRedirected' as a global variable. is there a better place to put it?

Comment: the better solution is to separate parsing the command line from redirecting the output.  do the output redirection in the child process of the fork.